Passing message from javascript to c++ using protobuf and WASM
Please tell me where I'm wrong. I use protobuf for interaction between javascript and c++
There is person.proto which defines
syntax = "proto2";
package tutorial;

message Person {
    optional int32 id = 1;
}

There is javascript code
const obj = new WebAssembly.Instance(...);

load("person.proto", function(err, root) {
    // Create an instance of Person
    const Person = root.lookupType("tutorial.Person");
    let message = Person.create({ id: 52 });
    let personData = Person.encode(message).finish();

    // Write to memory
    const strOffset = obj.exports.getStrOffset(personData.byteLength + 1);
    let memory = new Uint8Array(obj.exports.memory.buffer, strOffset, personData.byteLength + 1);
    memory.set(personData);

    // Get the identifier for verification
    console.log(obj.exports.setPersonDataAndGetPersonId(personData.byteLength));
});

There is code in c++
#include "person.pb.h"

char *message;
tutorial::Person *person

char* EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE getStrOffset(const int size) {
 if (message) {
 delete message;
 message = nullptr;
 }
 message = new char [size];
 return message;
}

int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE setPersonDataAndGetPersonId(int size) {
 tutorial::Person *person = new tutorial::Person();

 absl::string_view serialized(message, size);

 // serialized.size() // 2
 // serialized[0] // 16
 // serialized[1] // 52

 person->ParseFromString(serialized); // Fail

 return person->id();
}

The ParseFromString function does not work. There is a feeling that something other than two bytes is expected there
I also tried ParseFromArray, but I got signature errors
Cpp is built with the command
emcc -L ./lib -lprotobuf idw.cpp ./proto/addressbook.pb.cc -Oz -s WASM=1 -s --no-entry -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0 -s STANDALONE_WASM -o idw.wasm -lstdc++

How to pass message from javascript to c++?
I will be very grateful for any advice.
AAAAAND
Okay, I decided to check if I'm crazy
// C++
const void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE qwe() {
std::string data;
tutorial::Person person;

person.set_name("qwe");
person.set_id(52);
person.set_email("qwe");

person.SerializeToString(&data); // null function or function signature mismatch
}

// Build
// emcc -L ./lib -lprotobuf qwe.cpp ./proto/person.pb.cc -Oz -s WASM=1 -s --no-entry -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0 -s STANDALONE_WASM -o idw.wasm -lstdc++

// Javascript
const obj = new WebAssembly.Instance(idwModule, importObject);
obj.exports.qwe();

I don't understand what's going on. Basic stuff doesn't work

Your question isn't a minimal repro of your issue: you don't include libraries and you omit values (WebAssembly.Instance(...)) making more work for people to help you. You don't include the output from your JavaScript code which would provide the binary data that the JavaScript is producing and which you expect to be written to the WASM code. You say ParseFromString doesn't work but don't show the actual output (or value it receives from the WASM code).
